# While loop inside While working just once in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using while statement in ruby and another child while statement in that parent while to print :

```
z = 0
  i = 0
  while z < 2
    puts "hi coding"
        while i < 4  do
          puts "hello"
           i +=1
        end
    z +=1
  end
```

I want first ("hi coding") is printed and then ("hello,hello,hello,hello" four times) ,  and this total chunk printed twice but what is happening is that hi coding is printed twice and ( 4 times hello just once ):
so my output is like :

```
hi coding 
hello 
hello
hello
hello
hi coding
*************************
```

but i want it as :

```
hi coding
hello
hello
hello
hello
hi coding
hello
hello
hello
hello
*************************
```

what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: hint: maybe you should not start the inner loop where it ended the last time.

Comment: Bonus hint:  try putting  i=0 somewhere else

Comment: @JanDvorak can you please be more specific ?

Comment: Hint #2: what's the value of `i` when you enter the inner loop the second time?

Comment: I guess after the first loop the value of i is already = 4?!

Comment: thanks guys it worked actually after the first loop value of i = 5 so it never ran second time , thanks for the help , it was silly of me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your first loop, the value of `i` is already 4 and thus no further 'hello' is printed. 
Change your code to this:

```
z = 0
  while z < 2
    puts "hi coding"
    i = 0
      while i < 4  do
        puts "hello"
        i +=1
      end
   z +=1
end
```

Comment: Fix the indentation, while you're at it :)

Answer (score 4):

I'll offer you a more fabulous alternative:

```
2.times do
  puts 'hi coding'
  4.times { puts 'hello' }
end
```

Comment: `times` is really the way to do this.

Comment: @ndn yes. This is really the nicer solution, thx for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with **nested-while loop** like this way:

```
main = 0
begin
  puts "Hi Coding"
  puts "*" * 10
  inner = 0
  begin
    puts "Hello"
    inner += 1
  end while inner < 4
  main += 1
end while main < 2
```

### Output:

```
Hi Coding
**********
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hi Coding
**********
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```